# How to draw a background behind a plotLine label in a highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw a background behind a plotLine label in a highstock chart.
Using an example from the Highstock API, I came up with this code (crt is the chart object):

```
        var textbox = crt.yAxis[ 0 ].plotLinesAndBands[ 0 ].label;
        var box = textbox.getBBox();
        crt.renderer.rect(box.x - 3, box.y + 1, box.width + 6, box.height, 3).attr({
            fill: '#0c0',
            id: 'labelBack',
            opacity: .7,
            'stroke-width': 0,
            zIndex: 4
        }).add();
```

This draws a semi-transparent box behind the label as intended (the label has zIndex 5). However when the chart is resized, the box maintains the same position relative to the top-left of the chart, causing misalignment with the label text (the position of the label changes because of the chart resizing).
I tried using the chart redraw event for this, but even though I can see that the event is fired, and the function is executed again, no other boxes are drawn (I was trying to get more boxes to appear on each redraw, planning to solve removing obsolete boxes in the next iteration).
How can I solve this?

Comment: In redraw even use this instead of crt. Could you setup example in jsFiddle? It should the way you have described.

Comment: Indeed, you can use 'this' inside the redraw event. However my setup is more complex because I have separate functions creating the graph options and the graph itself, see my own answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels more like a hack than a genuine solution, but I have come up with a workaround that solves my issue for now, I have the function below:

```
var labelBackground = null;
function labelDrawBack(crt) {
    if ( isIntraDay ) {
        var textbox = crt.yAxis[ 0 ].plotLinesAndBands[ 0 ].label;
        if ( !!labelBackground ) {
            labelBackground.attr({ y: textbox.y - 10 });
        } else {
            var box = textbox.getBBox();
            labelBackground = crt.renderer.rect( box.x - 3, box.y + 1, box.width + 6, box.height, 3 ).attr( {
                fill: '#fff',
                id: 'labelBack',
                opacity: .65,
                'stroke-width': 0,
                zIndex: 4
            }).add();
        }
    }
}
```

I make sure this function is executed immediately after the chart is initialized and additionally I attach the function to the chart object that is returned from the StockChart call:

```
var chartObj = new Highcharts.StockChart( chartConfig, function ( crt ) {
        labelDrawBack( crt );
} );
chartObj.labelDraw = labelDrawBack;
```

And in the chart options I have added this to the chart.redraw event:

```
events: {
    redraw: function() {
        this.labelDraw(this);
    }
}
```

This works as intended, moving the transparent background with the label (which is moved vertically when the chart is resized).
The reason I have redirected the call in the chart redraw event is that the labelDrawBack function is defined in another function than the one where my chart options are defined, thus the labelDrawBack function is out of scope there.

Comment: I have made another change to my solution: I've split up the labelDrawBack function into 2 separate functions, one for creation of the label background and one for moving it at runtime.